# How to resolve dependent object with unity with a registered name set on a primary object property?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, unity-container

I have a little problem resolving types with Unity.

There's an example of what I want to do:

```
public class MainClass
{
    public void MainMethod()
    {
        UnityContainerHelper.DefaultContainer.Resolve<FirstClass>(new ParameterOverride("Property1", "SomeValue"));
        UnityContainerHelper.DefaultContainer.Resolve<FirstClass>(new ParameterOverride("Property1", "OtherValue"));
    }
}


public class FirstClass
{
    [InjectionMethod]
    public void DoSomething(SecondClass sc)
    {

    }
}

public class SecondClass
{
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    [InjectionMethod]
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        UnityContainerHelper.DefaultContainer.Resolve<ThirdClass>(this.Property1);
    }
}

public class ThirdClass
{
}
```

EDIT: Is there a way to configure Unity to resolve my ThirdClass by name, when I'm resolving my FirstClass?

The problem is that I only want to explicitly resolve FirstClass, and by configuration, tell Unity that "use that ThirdClass" when resolving the SecondClass. Am I clear?

I'm trying to do a "resolving layer" to do this stuff, but I wonder if there is a simple way to do it.

Comment: Could you please write in prose what your problem is. As it looks to me the code is part of the solution, not of the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could tell to Unity to use Factory Methods to resolve your classes the way you want...

look at:
https://bitbucket.org/ctavares/unityfactoryconfig/downloads
i got from:
http://unity.codeplex.com/discussions/219565?ProjectName=unity